# Is it correct to start a hypothetical or future tense sentence with "if I am..."?

Tags: tenses

My partner frequently starts sentences with "If <present tense statement>" where the present tense statement is referring to a future or hypothetical situation.

Examples:

- "If I am 60 and bored, I want to ..."
- "If I am a cat, I want to be an orange one."
- "If I can't finish the food, can you help me?"

Is this tense of the conditional statement correct? I usually use the hypothetical tense (which is usually the same as completed past tense), hence the present tense sounds wrong to me. Now I wonder, which form is correct - or are both? What does it depend on?

Comment: [There's a similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/414614/if-i-am-to-pick-a-favourite-or-if-i-were-to-pick-a-favourite) although it was closed; one answer suggests that "If I am" expresses obligation, although "If I was/were" are more common as conditionals.

Answer (score 3):

*If-clauses* about the future are very commonly expressed with the present tense:

- If it rains tomorrow...
- If she wins the next election...
- If temperatures continue to rise...

So there is nothing wrong with your examples.

The past tense could be used in the examples if you are referring informally not to the future but to a hypothetical or counterfactual present:

- If I was 60 and bored, I would want...
- If I was a cat, I would want...

In formal English the irrealis "*were*" is used here instead of past tense "*was*" (*If I were a cat...*)

Note that it is possible to use the past tense in the *if-clause* when referring to future events (*If it rained tomorrow...* / *If she won the next election...*). The past tense here typically expresses a greater doubt that the future event will occur.

Comment: "The past tense here typically expresses a greater doubt that the future event will occur." <--- No, it just indicates that the speaker is thinking abstractly. I know, I tested the 'doubt/counterfactuality' theory on over 1,000 native speakers. It failed. Spectacularly!

Comment: @Araucaria. I know you are a fan of H&P's _A Student's Introduction to English Grammar_. On page 47 it states in respect of the sentence _If you left now, you'd miss the rush-hour traffic_ >> "[The past tense] presents your leaving as somewhat less likely that in the case of [If you leave]". Your research sounds interesting. Is it available anywhere?

Comment: That's a bit like asking Banksy for their real name! I've emailed something to you at your organisation/website. Hope that's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Archetypal is say 'If O'Sullivan wins the World Championship again, he will hold the record outright.' The use of the indicative instead of the irrealis to refer to possible scenarios is common and acceptable to most, and the use of simple present is used for both present

- *If he's already in Cairo he's made good time*                             ['s = is]

and future

- *If I can't finish the food, can/will you help me?*                         [can't = cannot]

possibilities.

The latter (looking at a future rather than a present possibility) usage is called in more basic treatments the 'first conditional' construction:

> In first conditional sentences, the structure is usually: if/when +
> present simple >> will + infinitive.
>
> - *If I see her, I'll tell her.*
>
> We use the first conditional when we talk about future situations we
> believe are real or possible.

[[British Council_LearnEnglish](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/conditionals-zero-first-second)] [re-ordered]

**However**, the article mentioned goes on to discuss another structure, known in more basic treatments as the 'second conditional' construction. Fronting the usage note for emphasis:

> The second conditional is used to imagine present or future situations
> that are impossible or unlikely in reality.
>
> - *If we had a garden, we could have a cat.*
> - *If I won a lot of money, I'd buy a big house in the country.*
> - *I wouldn't worry if I were you.*
>
> The structure is usually: if + past simple >> + would + infinitive.
>
> When if is followed by the verb be, it is grammatically correct to say
> [using the irrealis form] *if I were*, *if he were*, *if she were* and
> *if it were*. However, it is also common to hear these structures with [the indicative] *was*, especially in the he/she form.
>
> - *If I were you, I wouldn't mention it.*
> - *If she was prime minister, she would invest more money in schools.*
> - *He would travel more if he was younger.*

So 'If I were a cat, I would want to be an orange one' is the preferred choice as the likelihood is a small one. Unless one is using the transferred usage: 'Jan wants me to act in the Christmas panto again this year. If I am a cat, I want to be an orange one.'

I find 'If I am 60 and bored, I want to ...' a strained example. 'If I'm bored when I get to 60, ... sounds far more natural, without some rather demanding (to think up!) context. I think the problem is that [reaching 60] and [being bored] are two widely different (semantically speaking) future possibilities.

Comment: Imagine you're trying to market a product to 60-year olds. Your friends are coming up with daft ideas. You say "If I am 60 and bored, I want something new and exciting. I don't want to hark back to the eighties. I am old, not dead!"

Comment: You should be writing novels. Or work in advertising.